# Телеграмм Бот неверно сохраняет курс криптовалюты

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я пишу телеграмм бота и у меня вроде бы все работает, но увы не так как нужно. Вкратце скажу, что это за бот. Я сделал телеграмм бота, который с помощью парсера заходит на сайт, считывает какой курс биткоина в долларах и присылает человеку, через определенное время и сравнивает изменился ли курс биткоина. Если да, то он присылает новое значение курса человеку. Но я видимо не правильно сделал сохранение курс биткоина для того, чтобы бот сравнивал и отправлял, так как он отправляет чередующиеся значения (скрин прикрепил ниже).

```
import telebot
import requests
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

token = ""
channel_id = ""
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def commands(message):
    #bot.send_message(channel_id, message.text)
    if message.text == "Курс":
        #bot.send_message(channel_id, "Hello")
        back_post_id = None
        while True:
            post_text = parser(back_post_id)
            back_post_id = post_text[1]

            if post_text[0] != None:
                bot.send_message(channel_id, post_text[0])
                time.sleep(1)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши Курс")

def parser(back_post_id):
    URL = "https://currency.com/ru/btc-to-usd?utm_course=rbc&utm_campaign=quote"

    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

    post = soup.find("b", class_='i-price-buy').text
    post_id = post
    
    if post_id != back_post_id:
        post = soup.find("b", class_='i-price-buy').text
        
        return f"{post}", post_id
    else:
        return None, post_id

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

[image: вот скриншот]

Comment: Попробуй сделать переменую back_post_id глобальным

Comment: можешь по подробней объяснить

Comment: получается просто вместо (back_post_id = None)
написать (global back_post_id)
Или как я не совсем понял

Comment: https://pythonru.com/osnovy/globalnye-peremennye-python#h-global-1

Comment: у тебя есть тг? если есть можешь скинуть. просто здесь через коменты спрашивать это такое

Comment: я попробовал сделать глобальную переменную, ничего не изменилось. возможно я ее не правильно задал